# How to increase font size in looped multiple subplots

Tags: python, seaborn

I was wondering how can I increase the font size in all my subplots in the loop I made.
I plan to simultaneously plot the box plots for all the groups, and each plot represents a numeric variable in the data set.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,6,figsize = (60,60))
for i in range (37):
    if i != 0:
        xi = df.iloc[:,i]
        a = (i-1) % 6
        if i <= 6:
            b = 0
        elif i > 6 and i <= 12:
            b = 1
        elif i > 12 and i <= 18:
            b = 2
        elif i > 18 and i <= 24:
            b = 3
        elif i > 24 and i <= 30:
            b = 4
        else:
            b = 5
        sns.boxplot(x=xi, y="POI", data=df, orient="h",ax = axes[a,b])
plt.show()
```

I have tried this inside the loop:

```
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('XX', size = 20)
plt.xlabel('XXX', size = 20)
```

but it only changed the last subplot not all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice way is to use a [plotting context](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html#seaborn.plotting_context):

```
with sns.plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=1.5):
    # put all your plotting code here
```

You can change the `font_scale` to whatever you like.